# Is it possible to define a hook_preprocess function based on entity type such as profile2?

Tags: theming

I walked through the possible hooks by using function `hook_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)` and only entity was available to use. Is it possible to do something like `hook_preprocess_profile2_entity()`, or do I have to write an if condition to check the entity type in `hook_preprocess_entity()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This adapts the Zen theme pattern for node preprocess functions to entities:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_entity().
 *
 * Runs a entity specific preprocess function, if it exists.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_entity(&$variables, $hook) {
  $function = __FUNCTION__ . '_' . $variables['entity_type'];
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $function($variables, $hook);
  }
}

/**
 * Profile2 specific implementation of template_preprocess_entity().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_entity_profile2(&$variables, $hook) {
}

/**
 * Field Collection specific implementation of template_preprocess_entity().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_entity_field_collection_item(&$variables, $hook) {
}
```

Comment: This is awesome.  I always forget that PHP lets you do stuff like this.

Comment: If you want to do it in a parent theme and inherit/override, then you'll have to dig deeper into hook_theme. Zen's hook_theme is a good example (although lengthy).

Comment: I'd be grateful if someone showed me how I can achieve something similar outside of the theme layer! Driving me nuts...