# how to define template_preprocess for custom entity type in module?

Tags: theming, entities

i have a custom entity type defined in a module. I have extended Model entity project to create new entity type. My entity is themed with a key: myentity. Somehow template_preprocess_myentity() not working. Whats the right way to do this?

When I have tried:

```
hook_preprocess_myentity(&$variables){
  dpm($variables);
}
```

i could see in theme registry that theme template funtion 'myentity' has hook_preprocess_myentity listed inside the 'preprocess functions' array. Only problem is that its not being processed. And i did flush the cache.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/is-it-possible-to-define-a-hook-preprocess-function-based-on-entity-type-such-as

Comment: almost. i wanted cleaner way of doing this without having it theme dependent. i am using garland theme for testing and later it will change, maybe several times.

Comment: i finally managed to got it working. Basically what i wanted to do was to have an entity template preprocess function which is specific to the entity type that i defined in the module. I extended EntityAPIController and overrided view() function so that my entity uses 'myentity' theme function rather than 'entity'. Then i implemented template_preprocess_myentity() and handled extra entity type specific values there.

Comment: (pre)processors can be placed in a custom module to be theme independent. Your solution seems overly complicated. In your question, did you name the function `hook_preprocess_myentity` with that specific prefix ("hook_")? Think of "hook" and "template" as placeholders. They should be replaced by your custom module or by your custom theme. [This should get you started.](http://drupal.org/node/223430)