# how to define entity preprocess function

Tags: 7, theming, entities

My custom module defines a custom entity, which extends the EntityAPIController class. I managed to make it basically working, i.e. displaying fields etc via my custom tpl.php file. But I would like to create a `mymodule_preprocess_entity` function (as suggested [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/is-it-possible-to-define-a-hook-preprocess-function-based-on-entity-type-such-as)) to add custom variables to the tpl.php file. But such function is not running (is not called).

Also, when I display this entity, I noticed that the function `template_preprocess_entity(&$variables)` from entity.module is not running, either.

What else needs to be defined to make the preprocess function for custom entity being called?

Comment: your using mymodule - the suggestion uses mytheme

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a general `mymodule_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)` function and it showed that the specific function name should be `mymodule_preprocess_myentity`. Where `myentity` is the proper name of the entity.

So, this code is working for me:

```
function mymodule_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#entity_type'])) { // or maybe check for $hook name
    $function = __FUNCTION__ . '_' . $variables['elements']['#entity_type'];
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $function($variables, $hook);
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_preprocess_myentity(&$vars) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generic approach:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#entity_type'])) {
    $myhook = "preprocess_{$variables['elements']['#entity_type']}_{$variables['elements']['#bundle']}_{$variables['elements']['#view_mode']}";
    $modules = module_implements($myhook);

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
      $function = "{$module}_{$myhook}";
      $function($variables);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately `module_implements()` doesn't check if the active theme implements the preprocess hook.