# How do I template preprocess our custom entity?

Tags: theming, entities

I can preprocess node and page in a Drupal 8 template file, but I am not able to preprocess our custom entity. Is there anyway we can preprocess custom entities?

Comment: Give this a try, [how to define entity preprocess function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/how-to-define-entity-preprocess-function). I don't think anything has changed in D8 for this.